# Does $f(x,y) \space \epsilon \space L^1(\Bbb{R}^2)$ imply that that $f_x(y) \space \epsilon \space L^1(\Bbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

My question is as follows:  If $f(x,y)$ is a function on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (real or complex valued) and $f_x$ is defined as the function on $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$ for all $y \space \epsilon \space \Bbb{R} $ then does  $f \space \epsilon \space L^1(\Bbb{R}^2)$ imply that $ f_x \space \epsilon \space L^1(\Bbb{R})$ for every $x \space \epsilon \space \Bbb{R}$?  I know the conclusion holds for almost all $x$ since $$ \Vert f \Vert_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert f_x(y)\vert dy \lt \infty $$ which implies that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert f_x(y)\vert dy \lt \infty $ almost everywhere (i.e. for almost all $x$ in $\Bbb{R}$).  I'm just wondering if there is a way to prove the stronger conclusion that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert f_x(y)\vert dy \lt \infty $ for all $x$ in $\Bbb{R}$.  If the given assumptions on $f$ don't guarantee the stronger conclusion, are there any additional assumptions we can make about $f$ which would?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: An $L^1$ function is generally not even _defined_ for all values of $x$ (remember, an element of $L^1$ is an equivalence class of functions). So “almost every $x$” is really the best we can hope for.

Comment: @csch2 you can still formulate the question where $f$ is a well defined function that happens to have $L^1$ integrability.  Then the conclusion about integrability of $f_x$ is of course false without further assumptions (modify $f$ to equal $1$ on $y$-axis), but you can still ask what happens if you put further assumptions on $f$, eg, assume further that $f$ is continuous (still false I believe) or assume $f$ is uniformly continuous or even Lipschitz (then it’s not so clear to me either way)

Comment: Answer can be found in For Integrable Functions section of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#